# Simple Node.JS application to read / write to a local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, http

I have a file with 10 variables stored in it, locally on my system. I want this to be available to someone else when they connect to my system. **This will be used within my LAN  only and not over the internet so there is no need to worry about security.**  I want to create a simple client-server application that uses HTTP request/response to communicate.

I can work with HTML and Javascript but I have limited knowledge of Node JS. I have created a HTML page with 10 blank labels and a "show" button. When I click on the button, I want the file to be read and each of the 10 variables to be displayed in the labels.
Here is a sample with two variables and a button.

```
**index.html**
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/">
<fieldset>
<legend><h2>Parameters:</h2></legend>
System ID : <textarea name="my_id" id="my_id" size="2"></textarea><br >
System IP : <textarea name="my_ip" id="my_ip"  size="15"></textarea><br>
<input id="show" type="submit" name="show" value="SHOW"><br>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I go about this? Is there any easier way besides Node JS ?
If this works I would also like to over-write the variables in the same file with the user's inputs (using a different "submit" button).

Comment: On the net, this could be done with Google Form and/or Google Sheet without writing any code. Is that easier?

Comment: No, I said that I can not use it over the internet.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) instead of node.  For node most people would use the [Express](http://expressjs.com/) library for the HTTP functions and routing of requests but even then you'll still be working at a fairly low level. Meteor is great for simple single page apps.

Comment: Meteor seems to be helpful, I'll tinker with it for a while and be back with the result. Thanks for the quick reply, Paul.

Comment: Meteor turned out to be huge (user friendly but not concise) and not exactly what I was looking for. Anyways, thanks for your help, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using the http module along with the fs module for this but since you are still learning nodejs, I would recommend [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) and [flat-file-database](https://www.npmjs.org/package/flat-file-db)

So when you are creating routes for your small webapp, it would probably look like this :

```
// Serves html file
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
});

// Stores data from the form
app.post('/form', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    db.put('data', data); // Saves data to the flat file db
    res.status(201);
});

// Gets data from the db
app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
    var data = db.get('data');
    res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

You would need to 'post' the data at /form in your client side code.
To get the data, simply issue a get request at /form

Also keep in mind that for express to parse form data, you need the [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser?_ga=1.137941816.921498117.1410010359).
Oh and note that I have no idea whether flat-file db is asyncronous or not so you will probably need to check that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this. What if I did receive those 10 variables from the get request? Will the body-parser give me each variable separately so I can set it in the fields?

Comment: If you are issuing a get request, express probably has an in-build querystring parser which can show your variables inside req.query.
And it will give you the variables in a js object, not an array unless you are sending it in an array from client side.

Comment: I am having a really hard time getting my head around this. If I request for the variables using the "show" button, it will redirect me to a different page with the result. How do I get it to fill in the text area boxes I have set up on the same page?

Comment: For getting the data, I suggest using a templating engine or simply inserting data inside html php-style.
So if you send a get request, you should write something like this :
res.send('<input type="text" value="' + variable + '>');

Comment: So I need to create a similar webpage with the res.send and insert the  values manually? But won't it break when I click "show" again on the new page ?

Comment: No it will just resend. I highly recommend you look up on nodejs templating engines and understand how the express framework works. Its all quite simple, you just need to think in terms of routes and methods.